# How can I load a list in a web part based on a selection from another web part?

Tags: 2010, web-part, list, calendar, custom

I have two lists, one with data about a group of elements, and the other with calendars to be used for creating schedules for these elements. I've set up a page with two list views; one showing the list of elements on a left panel, and the rest of the page showing a calendar. How can I change the calendar in the main view, based on the selection from the left panel?

More info: I've tried to add a connection between the two Web Parts, and my calendar Web Part complains that it does not support connections. If I could find a function that allows to change the underlying data source for a Web Part, that would likely solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of this page on the Office Help site for creating connections between web parts on a page.

[Connect Data in Web Parts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-data-in-web-parts-HA010024105.aspx)

It's designed for SharePoint 2007 but I think the workings and the dialogs are the same in 2010, though they might look slightly different.

Comment: Hmm yeah, that seems like it would likely work in most instances, but I get a "The <webpartname> Web Part does not support connections." message. This is the case for any calendar web part I add. It doesn't seem like there's any way to set the data source through a connection from another Web Part as far as I know.